# Class Name Does not Name a Type Issues with Templated Inheritance

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, namespaces

Pure Virtual Class, AbstractThing.hpp:

```
#ifdef ABSTRACT_INTERFACE_FOR_THING
#define ABSTRACT_INTERFACE_FOR_THING

namespace A
{
namespace B 
{

template <class T>
class AbstractThing
{
public:
  virtual ~AbstractThing() = 0;
  virtual T    GetStatus() = 0; 
};

}
}
#endif
```

Header File, Thing.hpp:

```
#ifdef _THING_H
#define _THING_H

#include "AbstractThing.hpp"
namespace A 
{   
namespace B 
{
template <class T>
class Thing : public AbstractThing<T> {
public:
  Thing();  
  ~Thing();
  T  GetStatus(); 
};

}
}

#endif
```

Source file, Thing.cpp,

```
#include "Thing.hpp"

namespace A
{
namespace B
{
template <class T>
Thing<T>::Thing() {}

template <class T>
Thing<T>::~Thing() {}

template <class T>
T Thing<T>::GetStatus() { ... }
}
}
```

I keep running into this issue where compiler the complains about the class name (Thing) not being a type.  However, it is declared in the header file.  From reading other posts, it seems like this issue is generally caused by failing to pre-declare a function or class.  However, I don't see why my code does not accomplish this.  I thought that it might be a namespace issue because GetStatus() will compile if I remove the namespace access (Thing::), but removing the namespaces did not help.

Comment: Do not use identifiers that start with an underscore followed by a capital letter like `_THING_H`. These are reserved for the implementation (compiler and standard library).

Comment: I was unaware of that.  Thank you for the information.

Answer (score 1):

```
#ifdef ABSTRACT_INTERFACE_FOR_THING
```

and

```
#ifdef _THING_H
```

should be:

```
#ifndef ABSTRACT_INTERFACE_FOR_THING
   ^
```

and

```
#ifndef _THING_H
   ^
```

And as suggested by @Amadeus, [templates shouldn't be implemented in source files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file).

Comment: Thanks for catching that!